# millions of non-breaking spaces in an ASPX file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Has anyone ever seen an instance where Visual Studio (or possibly SourceSafe) would decide to insert about 9 million non-breaking space characters at the end of a line in an ASPX file?

I'm trying to figure out if this could be some weird bug, or if a programmer fell asleep with her head on the space bar, while in design view... and then went ahead and checked the page into SourceSafe without noticing what she'd done.

Comment: Thats an impressive amount of spaces, did you count them?

Comment: *Non* breaking spaces?  Or just spaces?  If the latter, I'd blame the local cat.

Comment: non-breaking spaces (&nbsp;).  I could see them getting inserted in design view, if you sat on the space bar there.  The weird thing is that they appeared in two different places in the same source file, both times near a 'fieldset' tag.  And someone else here told me that this has happened once before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard of that one.  My guess would be as good as your guess.  If you are seeing it a lot then there might be some issue to worry about.  If it is just that one page I'd clean it up and then move on.